# R ggplot barplot separately for each year

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I would like to know how to get a barplot where data are separately for each year. I'd like to add an Excel-image, but I couldn't cause I'm new in this forum. 
I have following data in a data frame:

```
Year    2009/10    2010/11    2011/12     2012/13    2013/14
V1     -221.85      0.00       0.00      -138.73     -191.10
V2       0.00     -223.16    -231.52       0.00      -126.85
V3       0.00     -1216.17   -1337.28    -1112.11    -863.98
V4       0.00     -520.87    -540.88     -174.85     -296.78
V5       0.00     -465.48    -805.63     -252.38     -178.92
V6       0.00     -496.25      0.00        0.00      -232.17
V7       0.00       0.00       0.00      -709.63     -759.41
```

Please could anyone help me - I have tried different approaches but without success.

Many thanks in advance

steff

Comment: So what's supposed to go on the x- and y-axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for..

```
dat <- structure(list(var = structure(1:7, .Label = c("V1", "V2", "V3",  "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "factor"), `2009` = c(-221.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2010` = c(0, -223.16, -1216.17, -520.87, -465.48, -496.25, 0), `2011` = c(0, -231.52, -1337.28, -540.88, -805.63, 0, 0), `2012` = c(-138.73, 0, -1112.11, -174.85, -252.38, 0, -709.63), `2013` = c(-191.1, -126.85, -863.98, -296.78, -178.92, -232.17, -759.41)), .Names = c("var", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

names(dat) <- c("var", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013")
dat.m <- melt(dat)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=var)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first column naming things. If you wanna name by first row, use read.table with h=TRUE when importing into R.
Export from Excel as csv where sep= is your separator and use:

> data <- read.table(pathToCSV, h=TRUE, sep="")
>   barplot(as.matrix(data))

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply!
I have now my data in a propper format in r - but when I plot now the date, all data from one year are in one bar togther. how it is possible to seperate them, that each value has it's own bar?

THANKS!

Comment: As beetroot mentioned, its hard to understand what ur actually trying to do. Paste your Code so far or explain in greater detail what you are trying to achieve.